# "sphinx_fe.c", line 133: Number of channels 2 does not match configured value

Tags: sphinx, cmusphinx, pocketsphinx

i am trying to create speech recognizer for my native speaking language(Serbian) i followed steps described in this documentation https://cmusphinx.github.io/wiki/tutorialam/ and when running command

`python ../sphinxtrain/scripts/sphinxtrain run`

i keep getting this error

[image]

Any kind of help is welcome!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed it, the .wav file needs to have:

- bit resoulution: 16
- sample rate: 16 KHz
- audio channels: mono